# HTML Form not Functioning in Table?

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I have a `<form>`  tag, and inside is a table width td's, and inside those are `<input type="radio">`'s. However, when I select a radio button, I can select others, and the other radios do not deselect. If I put the form INSIDE the table, it automatically closes it.. So it looks like `<form></form>`

What's wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your HTML.

Comment: Got any source code? This would help analyzing your problem.

Comment: What do you mean with "it automatically closes it."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to use the same value in the "name" attribute for the radio inputs:
example

```
<input type="radio" name="var1" value="A"> 
<input type="radio" name="var1" value="B">
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! Wish I had 15 rep so I could up your post!